# GORM doesn't fill the foreign key id when doin an insert into

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have the following structs:

```
type Player struct {
    ID                       uint `gorm:"primarykey"`
    ClubID                   uint
    Club                     Club
}
type Club struct {
    ID   uint `gorm:"primarykey"`
    Name string `gorm:"unique"`
}
```

I'm loading this info from a file, something like:

```
func TestSQLite(t *testing.T) {

    pr, err := db.Init("file:memdb1?mode=memory&cache=shared")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error on Init: " + err.Error())
        t.Fail()
    }

    p := domain.Player{
        Club: domain.Club{Name: "Hello"},
        Shooting: 23,
        PlayerPositions: []domain.Position{
            {
                Name: "SM",
            },
        },
    }
    if err := pr.Create(&p); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error creating player: " + err.Error())
        t.Fail()
    }
    c := domain.Player{
        Club: domain.Club{Name: "Hello"},
        Shooting: 23,
        PlayerPositions: []domain.Position{
            {
                Name: "SM",
            },
        },
    }
    if err := pr.Create(&c); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error creating player: " + err.Error())
        t.Fail()
    }

    t.Logf("%d", p.ClubID)
    t.Logf("%d", c.ClubID)
    if c.ClubID != p.ClubID {
        t.Fail()
    }
}
```

and as result I have:

```
    db_test.go:45: 1
    db_test.go:46: 0
```

Code for Create is

```
    return pr.preload().Debug().Create(&p).Error
```

and preload is

```
func (pr *PlayerRepository) preload() *gorm.DB {
    return pr.connection.
        Preload("Club")
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I forgot to add debug information:

```
=== RUN   TestSQLite

2020/12/27 19:39:56 /Users/emanuele/personal/roadmap/io/db/db.go:41
[0.059ms] [rows:1] INSERT INTO `clubs` (`name`) VALUES ("Hello") ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING

2020/12/27 19:39:56 /Users/emanuele/personal/roadmap/io/db/db.go:41
[0.032ms] [rows:1] INSERT INTO `positions` (`name`) VALUES ("KM") ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING

2020/12/27 19:39:56 /Users/emanuele/personal/roadmap/io/db/db.go:41
[0.026ms] [rows:1] INSERT INTO `player_positions` (`player_id`,`position_id`) VALUES (1,1) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING

2020/12/27 19:39:56 /Users/emanuele/personal/roadmap/io/db/db.go:41
[0.659ms] [rows:1] INSERT INTO `players` (`player_url`,`short_name`,`long_name`,`age`,`date_of_birth`,`height`,`weight`,`nationality_id`,`club_id`,`league_id`,`league_rank`,`overall`,`potential`,`value`,`wage`,`preferred_foot`,`international_reputation`,`weak_foot`,`skill_moves`,`work_rate`,`body_type`,`real_face`,`release_clause_eur`,`team_position_id`,`team_jersey_number`,`loaned_from`,`joined`,`contract_valid_until`,`nation_position_id`,`nation_jersey_number`,`pace`,`shooting`,`passing`,`dribbling`,`defending`,`physic`,`goal_keeper_diving`,`goal_keeper_handling`,`goal_keeper_kicking`,`goal_keeper_reflexes`,`goal_keeper_speed`,`goal_keeper_positioning`,`attacking_crossing`,`attacking_finishing`,`attacking_heading_accuracy`,`attacking_short_passing`,`attacking_volleys`,`skill_dribbling`,`skill_curve`,`skill_fk_accuracy`,`skill_long_passing`,`skill_ball_control`,`movement_acceleration`,`movement_sprint_speed`,`movement_agility`,`movement_reactions`,`movement_balance`,`power_shot_power`,`power_jumping`,`power_stamina`,`power_strength`,`power_long_shots`,`mentality_aggression`,`mentality_interceptions`,`mentality_positioning`,`mentality_vision`,`mentality_penalties`,`mentality_composure`,`defending_marking`,`defending_standing_tackle`,`defending_sliding_tackle`,`goal_keeping_diving`,`goal_keeping_handling`,`goal_keeping_kicking`,`goal_keeping_positioning`,`goal_keeping_reflexes`,`left_striker`,`striker`,`right_striker`,`left_winger`,`left_forward`,`center_forward`,`right_forward`,`right_winger`,`left_attacking_midfielder`,`central_attacking_midfielder`,`right_attacking_midfielder`,`left_midfielder`,`left_centre_midfielder`,`central_midfielder`,`right_centre_midfielder`,`right_midfielder`,`left_wing_back`,`left_defensive_midfielder`,`central_defensive_midfielder`,`right_defensive_midfielder`,`right_wing_back`,`left_back`,`left_center_attack`,`centre_back`,`right_centre_back`,`right_back`) VALUES ("","","",0,"",0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,"","",0,0,"","","",0,0,0,"","","",0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

2020/12/27 19:39:56 /Users/emanuele/personal/roadmap/io/db/db.go:41
[0.024ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO `clubs` (`name`) VALUES ("Hello") ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING

2020/12/27 19:39:56 /Users/emanuele/personal/roadmap/io/db/db.go:41
[0.023ms] [rows:1] INSERT INTO `positions` (`name`) VALUES ("SM") ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING

2020/12/27 19:39:56 /Users/emanuele/personal/roadmap/io/db/db.go:41
[0.026ms] [rows:1] INSERT INTO `player_positions` (`player_id`,`position_id`) VALUES (2,2) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING

2020/12/27 19:39:56 /Users/emanuele/personal/roadmap/io/db/db.go:41
[0.396ms] [rows:1] INSERT INTO `players` (`player_url`,`short_name`,`long_name`,`age`,`date_of_birth`,`height`,`weight`,`nationality_id`,`club_id`,`league_id`,`league_rank`,`overall`,`potential`,`value`,`wage`,`preferred_foot`,`international_reputation`,`weak_foot`,`skill_moves`,`work_rate`,`body_type`,`real_face`,`release_clause_eur`,`team_position_id`,`team_jersey_number`,`loaned_from`,`joined`,`contract_valid_until`,`nation_position_id`,`nation_jersey_number`,`pace`,`shooting`,`passing`,`dribbling`,`defending`,`physic`,`goal_keeper_diving`,`goal_keeper_handling`,`goal_keeper_kicking`,`goal_keeper_reflexes`,`goal_keeper_speed`,`goal_keeper_positioning`,`attacking_crossing`,`attacking_finishing`,`attacking_heading_accuracy`,`attacking_short_passing`,`attacking_volleys`,`skill_dribbling`,`skill_curve`,`skill_fk_accuracy`,`skill_long_passing`,`skill_ball_control`,`movement_acceleration`,`movement_sprint_speed`,`movement_agility`,`movement_reactions`,`movement_balance`,`power_shot_power`,`power_jumping`,`power_stamina`,`power_strength`,`power_long_shots`,`mentality_aggression`,`mentality_interceptions`,`mentality_positioning`,`mentality_vision`,`mentality_penalties`,`mentality_composure`,`defending_marking`,`defending_standing_tackle`,`defending_sliding_tackle`,`goal_keeping_diving`,`goal_keeping_handling`,`goal_keeping_kicking`,`goal_keeping_positioning`,`goal_keeping_reflexes`,`left_striker`,`striker`,`right_striker`,`left_winger`,`left_forward`,`center_forward`,`right_forward`,`right_winger`,`left_attacking_midfielder`,`central_attacking_midfielder`,`right_attacking_midfielder`,`left_midfielder`,`left_centre_midfielder`,`central_midfielder`,`right_centre_midfielder`,`right_midfielder`,`left_wing_back`,`left_defensive_midfielder`,`central_defensive_midfielder`,`right_defensive_midfielder`,`right_wing_back`,`left_back`,`left_center_attack`,`centre_back`,`right_centre_back`,`right_back`) VALUES ("","","",0,"",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"","",0,0,"","","",0,0,0,"","","",0,0,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
--- FAIL: TestSQLite (0.01s)
```

To add more info, maybe what I wanted to do is using a different reference like stated here: https://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html#Override-References

So I changed the structs this way:

```
type Club struct {
    ID   uint   `gorm:"primarykey"`
    Name string
}
type Player struct {
    ID                       uint `gorm:"primarykey"`
    ClubID                   string
    Club                     Club `gorm:"references:Name"`
}
```

but when I try now I get

```
[error] invalid field found for struct roadmap/domain.Player's field Club, need to define a foreign key for relations or it need to implement the Valuer/Scanner interface
```

Comment: the `Name` property in the `Club` struct is unique, so it doesn't get inserted the second time (according to your logs). It doesn't throw an error because it has `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, and because INSERT never happened, you don't get an ID from the `clubs` table.

Comment: @EminLaletovic but how do I do it then? The point was to not create the same Club many times but only create it the first time and then reuse it. How show I do it then?

Comment: There are a couple of options, it depends on what and how you want to do your operations. 1. You can first create a club, then assign it's ID to the players' `ClubID`. 2. You can create a first player like you tried, then use it's clubID to assign it to the other player. 3. There are some options for Upsert/On Conflict, but I haven't used these, so I don't know how it will work for your case https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Upsert-On-Conflict

Comment: I added some more info to something like https://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html#Override-References but still having problem. Your first suggestion means there is no reason to use an ORM if I need to do it manually. I will check the second suggestion.

Comment: @EminLaletovic no unfortunately it doesn't seem it works. I ended up removed the primary key as `uint` and I just have now a primary key `string` and it's working as expect. I have no idea why references is not working, I opened a github issue on gorm page to see if the creator knows more.

Comment: You are trying to use the Name as an identifier, but I don't think GORM likes to work that way (unless that column is named ID, or has the primaryKey tag). So specifying just the name and no ID in the second Create will attempt to create a second Club.

Gorm needs the ID somehow, so the way to do this is to save the Club if the club is new, then put the Club (or at least it's ID) in the new Player model before saving it. This may involve making extra queries to see if the club exists, or to retrieve its ID.

Comment: Yeah I basically solved just using the name as ID (as string). Thank you @EzequielMuns for the explanation. I think though that if I need to do what you are saying, there is no advantage in using GORM. And then the `references` keyword is not really working though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug. Jinzhu fixed it.

https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/3890